# macro: if radio button on then copy formula down a range

Tags: vba, excel

My prob is this:

I want to be able to use a macro to copy & calculate formula down a range of cells if radio button is on.
But I don't know how to set the variable inside the formula. The macro below should copy the formula to ranges shown (I12:I252, K12:K252, M12:M252).
The formula itself includes a subtraction of two cells in the range of C12:C252 & B12:B252. I cannot seem to reference those cells. I thinks that's the problem...

Anyway, it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
Dim shp1 As Shape
Dim shp2 As Shape
Dim i As Long

On Error Resume Next
Set shp1 = Worksheets("Worksheet").Shapes("Button 1")
Set shp2 = Worksheets("Worksheet").Shapes("Button 2")

If shp1.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
    MsgBox "Auto Calculating"
    For i = 12 To 252
        Range("I" & i).Formula = "=IFERROR(((C & i)-(B & i))*I6/(E7-E6);"")"
        Range("K" & i).Formula = "=IFERROR(((C & i)-(B & i))*J6/(E7-E6);"")"
        Range("M" & i).Formula = "=IFERROR(((C & i)-(B & i))*K6/(E7-E6);"")"
    Next i

Else

    If shp2.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
        MsgBox "Manually insert calculation"

    End If
End If
```

Comment: Replace the `;` in your formulas with `,`. `;` is your local setting, but `.Formula` uses the English setting!

Comment: although probably a good point (not sure) it doesn't seem to be the problem... Still nothing.

Comment: See my answer below - does it work now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few improvements:

1. Replace the `;` in your formulas with `,`. `;` is your local
   setting, but `.Formula` uses the English setting!
2. If you want to refer to each column, you need place the `i` outside the quoatation marks, i.e. instead of `=IFERROR(((C & i)...` write `=IFERROR(((C" & i & ")...`
3. No need to loop each cell and set the formula. If you use `$` in your formula properly, you can replace all with one formula: `=IFERROR(($C12-$B12)*I$6/($E$7-$E$6),"")`
4. Better use `.FormulaR1C1` - this way, your formula will also work, when you would applied it to some other range. To easily convert a formula, type it normally into a cell and the run `? Selection.FormulaR1C1`in the VBA Immediate Window. The above formula translates to `=IFERROR((RC3-RC2)*R6C/(R7C5-R6C5),"")`
5. Don't hard code cell references (in your case `I12:K252`). Better assign this range to a named range and use this as a reference. This way, your code will also work if you later add/remove rows or columns.
6. Don't use `On Error Resume Next`! This is a invitation to oversee an error that should be fixed
7. Optional: Alternatively to accessing the controls directly in VBA, you can also assign each one to a cell, name this cell as in step 4 and refer to in by this name. Makes your code more flexible/less complex!

So all in all, I end up with:

```
Public Sub YourSub()
    If Range("SwitchOne") Then
        Range("YourRange").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IFERROR((RC3-RC2)*R6C/(R7C5-R6C5),"""")"
    Else
        If Range("SwitchTwo") Then
            MsgBox "Manually insert calculation"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 For going the extra mile and providing excellent Suggestions :)

Comment: Perfect! I couldn't work it out because I used the IFERROR formula from your comments but then I noticed the quadruple quotation at the end of the formula. That was it. Efficient and prompt. Kudos!